# When user check the "Keep me signed in" on login page of the website, Should we also mention the duration?

Tags: website-design, forms, login, password-recovery

Should we do this?

[image]

or this is enough

[image]

Comment: Very interesting question! There are a lot of factors that play a role in wether the user would actually stay logged in for a year. You can't guarantee that even if you wanted to. Adding a little line to say 'We keep you logged in up to a year' is actually unusually transparent, but I like it.

Comment: Are you sure you can do this? This isn't a regular website using cookies? When the app fails to keep the user logged-in, they are sent to this screen which promises to keep them logged in for a year.

Answer (score 2):

If the duration is a year, nobody is going to track this for their own records and then keep you accountable if they are still logged in 1 year + 1 day from the initial login date. If you're set for 14 days or more, **it might as well just say "Keep me signed in." save the characters, have less clutter.**

However, a clarification on shorter time-spans such as "(for the rest of the day)" or "(24 hours)" might be noteworthy to the user. You can judge whether to use that by your user demographics.

Comment: Evernote mention 30 days https://www.evernote.com/Login.action

Comment: I should clarify that my use of 14 days was an arbitrary example. @JitendraVyas has pointed out a good example from a source with a reputation.